# Indefinite integral of $\frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{1+x^a}}$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Are there any special functions or other techniques to solve integrals of the form:

$\int\frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{1+x^a}}\ dx$

where $a$ is a real number?

If the numerator were just 1, for instance, then the solution can be written with hypergeometric functions.

Comment: Even for $a=2$, the result is [quite unwieldy](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sqrt%281%2Bx%29%2Fsqrt%281%2Bx%5E2%29) and requires elliptic integrals. I wouldn't hold out too much hope for there being a very neat general, closed form solution.

Comment: $a=3$ or $a=-1$ are simple though.

Comment: $a=5$ elliptic integrals again.

Comment: Big difference between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Specifying that $a$ is a real number was deliberate. I am aware that solutions can generally be found more easily for integer powers, but I am curious to see if there are any special functions that have been found that allow for solutions when there is an arbitrary real-valued (or if potentially rational) power under a radical.